# 'x' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to write something that checks if an integer (z) is within the bounds of x and y, x being the minimum number, y being the maximum. I do this by checking if z is less than the minimum number or more than the maximum number. If either of those are true it returns invalid, else it confirms it. The maximum, minimum and number to check values are determined by raw_input. Here's the code:

```
int(x = raw_input('x:\n')) #max number
int(y = raw_input('y:\n')) #min number
int(z = raw_input('z:\n')) #number to check.
if z < y:
    print 'invalid.'
elif z > x :
    print 'invalid.'
```

I can enter the x value fine, but when I try to enter the y value, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/random/bark", line 2, in <module>
    int(y = raw_input('y:\n')) #min number
TypeError: 'y' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I've asked elsewhere without answer.

Comment: python assignment does not return a value ... it thinks you are calling int with a named parameter x which is not allowed

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In place of this:

```
int(x = raw_input('x:\n')) #max number
```

try this:

```
x = int(raw_input('x:\n')) #max number
```

similarly for the other input statements.

Built-in Python function [raw_input()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input) "reads a line from input, converts it to a string ". In order for you to use to use the input as an integer, you need to convert the `string` to `int` with the help of the [int()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int) function which converts "a string or number to a plain integer". From your code it looks like you had the basic idea, but your syntax was a bit tangled up.

Comment: @user1524840: See my answer for a detailed explanation.

Comment: @user1524840 Happy I could help - I also added some additional explanation for you in case you are curious.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike in C, Python assignment statements can't be used as expressions in arguments.

For example, the following simply isn't legal, and will result in a `SyntaxError`:

```
if name = name + 1:
    pass
```

The reason you are receiving a `TypeError` instead of a `SyntaxError` in this case is because of Python's keyword argument feature. Python allows you to pass named arguments to functions in the form: `foo(arg1=0, second_argument="hello")`. Thus the interpreter thinks that this is what you're trying to do.

The error message your receiving is the result of the Python interpreter thinking that you are passing a keyword argument to `int()`. `int()`, of course, does not take the keyword argument "x" (or "y" or "z" for that matter), hence the error. This is what you should do instead:

```
x = int(raw_input("x:\n"))
y = int(raw_input("y:\n"))
z = int(raw_input("z:\n"))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
x,y,z, = int(raw_input("x:")),int(raw_input("y:")),int(raw_input("z:"))
```

this is the output

```
>>> x,y,z, = int(raw_input("x:")),int(raw_input("y:")),int(raw_input("z:"))
x:5
y:6
z:7
>>> x
5
>>> y
6
>>> z
7
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ever want a shorter version, try this:

```
x,y,z = (int(raw_input(var+':')) for var in "xyz")
```

(It works the same as Joran Beasley's version)